# Insert Into (col33) Select..trying to insert into col1 instead?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert data from one MV to columns 32 and 33 of a different table. For some reason even though I state to insert into col32 and col33, it gives me an error saying it can insert NULL into Col1. (Col1 cannot be NULL, so that is understandable, but I don't understand why it tries to insert into col1 instead of 32 and 33)

```
INSERT INTO T_1 (Col32, Col33) 
SELECT USER_Y.MV_1.PERS_FNAME, USER.MV_1.PERS_LNAME 
FROM USER_Y.MV_1 
JOIN T_1
ON T_1.Col1= USER_Y.MV_1.Col1
```

Running the SELECT query by itself works and shows the two columns of data I want. Again, for some reason the INSERT INTO line is trying to insert into Col1 instead of 32 and 33 on T_1

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error commonly occurs when you have defined Col1 as **primary key and/or NOT NULL** constraint. You can either **provide the value for Col1 too else add the default or auto-increment attribute when creating the table**

Comment: Could you explain more on providing the value for Col1? Col1 is already fully populated with data, I am trying to insert data in Col32 and Col33. Col1 is primary key and not null, using it to join table and mv rows on.

Comment: `INSERT` adds a new row to the database. `COL1` on your new row is not populated - only columns `COL32` and `COL33` are, as that's what you've said to do in your `INSERT` statement. You'll need to include `COL1` (at the very least - I don't know what else is in your table) in your `INSERT` statement, and provide a value for it. If what you want to do is to change the values of `COL32` and `COL33` on an existing row you should use an `UPDATE` statement.